# How much space an ascii character really takes on a 64 bit word addressable memory?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management, memory-hardware, memory-allocation

I know that an ASCII character needs 1 byte of memory for storage, but if a computer uses a 64-bit word addressable memory does it mean that the character actually takes 8 bytes even when only 1 byte was needed?

Does being a 64-Bit word addressable memory mean the same as being a 64-Bit machine?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  The usual rule is to ask only one question per post.  If you have two questions, you can ask them by making two separate posts.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  A program can store 1 ASCII character in each 64-bit word, or 8 ASCII characters in each 64-bit word.  It's up to each individual program to decide how it wants to store and format its data in memory.  The latter would probably be more typical.

Comment: Or you could be like old-school Haskell and say that a string is a cons list of pointers to character objects, because who needs memory?